# Replacement for Url.Link when using attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

I have upgraded my project from webapi to webapi2 and are now using attribute routing. I had a method where I used Url helper to get url. Which is the best way to replace Url helper (because this is not working for attributes).

My example code of old usage:

```
protected Uri GetLocationUri(object route, string routeName = WebApiConfig.RouteDefaultApi)
{
    string uri = Url.Link(routeName, route);
    return new Uri(uri);
}
```

Config of routes:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: RouteDefaultApi,
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Default" }
    );           
}
```

Usage:

```
Uri myUrl = GetLocationUri(route: new { action = "images", id = eventId });
```

Comment: Related (leave to someone else to decided which is duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/20234060/2181514

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Why are you trying to use the conventional route `RouteDefaultApi` when you want to generate links to an attributed route of a controller/action ?

Following is an example usage of how you need to use Url.Link with attribute routing:

```
[Route("api/values/{id}", Name = "GetValueById")]
public string GetSingle(int id)

Url.Link("GetValueById", new { id = 10 } );
```

Comment: Perfect, this was the solution I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Superb! I used a class constant - `private const string GET_VALUE_BY_ID = "GetValueById";` - and plugged that into the attribute and argument so the two stay connected if at one point some decides to rename it =)