# Using Url.Link with Attribute Routing in Webapi 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to add a Location header to my http response when using webapi 2. The method below shows how to do this using a named route. Does anyone know if you can create the Url.Link using Attribute Routing feature that was released as part of webapi 2?

```
string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = reponse.Id });
httpResponse.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use RouteName with Ur.Link when using attribute routing.

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/books/{id}", Name="GetBookById")]
    public BookDto GetBook(int id) 
    {
        // Implementation not shown...
    }

    [Route("api/books")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Book book)
    {
        // Validate and add book to database (not shown)

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);

        // Generate a link to the new book and set the Location header in the response.
        string uri = Url.Link("GetBookById", new { id = book.BookId });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
}
```

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-names

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
[Route("{id}", Name="GetById")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) 
{
    // Implementation...
}

public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] UsuarioViewModel usuarioViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest();

        var link = Url.Link("GetById", new { id = 1});

        var content = "a object";     
        return Created(link, content);
    }
```

Comment: This one really helped. Thanx